# UIWebView webViewDidFinishLoad not returning proper content size of embedded scrollView

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiwebview, mathjax

I'm loading mathml content to `UIWebView`, and sometimes the math expressions may cross my `webview` frame and user has to scroll to view that content which is out of border. So as to handle this kind of situations I'm showing an visual arrow indicator for user whenever their is a scrollable content.
My problem is, in my `webViewDidFinishLoad` if I try to access `webview`,`scrollView.contentSize` it is not returning me the exact content size but if I check this in some other method after some delay It is getting the proper content size. But checking with timer I don't think an efficient way to do this.
Below is my code snippet,

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    NSLog(@"contentSize %@",NSStringFromCGSize(webView.scrollView.contentSize));// returning worng values, even if content size is more this is returning default frame values of webview
    [self performSelector:@selector(checkContentSize) withObject:self afterDelay:1.5];//working properly after delay
}
```

How can I get proper content size of `webView` without using a `performSelector` after delay?

I have even tried [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13920512/detect-when-mathjax-has-finished-loading-in-uiwebview) as well and tried to capture that event in both `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` and `webViewDidFinishLoad` but even this of no use.

Answer (score 7):

Try this

```
 float height = [[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.documentElement.scrollHeight;"] floatValue];
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when `webViewDidFinishLoad`is called it means that the UIWebView has loaded the HTML content. But it has still to render the HTML to define the actual height of the HTML. This is why you get the correct size after a short delay.

The best way to get the correct height of the content is to add some Javascript to the content that sends the content size to the UIWebView once the HTML is fully rendered.

You find a short tutorial on how to do that in this [blogpost](http://www.pixeldock.com/blog/set-the-height-of-a-uiwebview-to-the-height-of-its-html-content/).

Comment: @joem Actually scalesPageToFit property has been enabled in my webview and the actual content which i'm getting is too large web content scalesPageToFit is resizing it and adjusting the content as per the iPhone window bounds, if i access like how you have said in your post i'm getting actual document content width and height which is too more than what webview has currently rendered after scalesPageToFit.